# Configuring a Git server

Tags: git

I'd like to set up a Git server for our team (4 people).

From what i've read so far, there are few options for doing so (part on Windows part on Linux).

I think i'll go for the Linux installation which seems more "native", unless there's a good reason not to?

Also, i'd like to know, what are the machine specs needed for such a server? Should we go with physical? vm? what are the considerations here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/1-INSTALL.html) is the way forward: updated and well-maintained. If you are on Debian or Redhat based distros the packages just work.

And I run it on my low-end Linode machine: it really doesn't require much juice, so running it on a not-very-powerful server should be fine.

Comment: Does it matter if we use HTTP or the git protocol? i've heard HTTP is really not usable...

Comment: I've heard the same: HTTP is basically not the way to go. Gitolite sets up an SSH user and then sends all the Git commands over SSH, so its completely secure out of the box and requires little in the way of extra configuration.

Comment: I am wondering why is the emphasis on SSH as this server is within our organization and not public facing, what go the extra mile to set up secure environment? or this is inherent in linux so there's not too much effort involved?

Comment: Its inherent, there is in fact little additional effort involved, it insulates you from future network topology changes (if your network gets re-orged for any reason you don't have to do anything different/new) and crucially it keeps your code protected regardless of the security of the rest of your network (if someone breaks into another machine on the network your Git repository is still secure). It is never a bad idea to deploy communication security layers, particularly where the tools make it so easy and transparent.

Comment: Thanks, what about machine specs? do you have any information regarding that? and a good tutorial on setting up an actual linux box with Git ?

Comment: I'm running it on both a Linode 512 machine (see the bottom of http://www.linode.com/index.cfm) and a 5 year old Dell desktop with a Pentium 4 processor that is running about 10 different other server processes. Git (at least via Gitolite) has no continuously running server process so it is only going to consume resources when a request is made. The link in my answer is to the Gitolite install guide, and on any modern linux desktop there will be client packages already available: on Debian `apt-get install git` installs the shell client and `apt-get install gitolite` installs the server.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [this](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) tutorial, it worked great. You don't need a real dedicated server for it, my current server is 2.2 ghz dualcore with 1 gb ram on debian squeeze and git doesn't consume much of it. Depending on your usage scenario, this might vary though.

Comment: I know Git wouldn't consume much resources, i am considering putting it on a virtual machine (VMware). Are there any considerations i must have in mind? (networking, cache, memory, etc?)

Comment: I don't think so. However, I don't really know how well the configuration scales, but unless you plan to have massively concurrent access, I don't see much of a problem.